# Extract function R - Raster package. Fun argument

Tags: r, extract, raster, shapefile

I have this line

extract(subset, countries, **fun**=mean , na.rm = TRUE)

I used the same function some months ago with the fun = mean, and by then it worked, and now it does not when I try to use again my script.

Right now I am trying to use it and I have to capitalize Fun = mean, for it to work. Do this things change over time? Like with updates or something? Cause I had a fully wotking script, which started getting many errors because of that.

This I have to do know for it to work:
extract(subset, countries, **F**un=mean , na.rm = TRUE)

thanks

Comment: The [documentation for the current version](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/raster.pdf) of `raster` still lists the argument as `fun`. It is a very standard argument name in R so I would quite surprised if that would change. Perhaps you have loaded a different package that masks the `extract` function (like `tidyr::extract`), or there is something else going on. A reproducible example would help.

Comment: ...or at least let us know what error message you are getting.

Comment: Okay, so this happens. I open a clear Rstudio session and type the following example code: `library(raster)
library(sf)
countries <- st_read("D:/Study Project/Model/1st_Approach/Input/SHP/BNDA_simplified_WGS8.shp")
raster <- stack("D:/Study Project/Model/1st_Approach/Input/RASTER/withd_dom.tif")
s <- subset(raster, 1)
z <- extract(s, countries, fun=mean)` and turns out it works perfectly. No error. But, if I open my old script and run it, the error appears again.

Comment: This are the libraries I call in my main script `library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(readxl)
library(sf) library(exactextract) library(terra) library(sp)` and the error is the following `extract raster Error in fun(res[[i]], na.rm = na.rm) : could not find function "fun"`

Comment: guess its a problem with your packages. terra, and raster both have extract functions. depending on your input file, extract does not expect fun argument. However, why would you use that, when you have loaded exactextract anyway.

Comment: 1) Have you updated your version of R since the last time you ran your code? 2) [And lot has happened since you last ran your code](https://github.com/r-spatial/evolution). So maybe deprecation is an issue in your case. 3) You could also try explicitly calling the associated package for the `extract()` function, so change it to something like `terra::extract()`. 4) It is heartbreaking when packages and/or functions are deprecated and code stops working. However this generally means there are much better options now. Still, annoying having to update code.

Comment: I encountered a very similar situation. Try adding the package name to the start of the package, similar to what L Tyrone suggested but calling for the raster package instead: `raster::extract()`. Also noteworthy, using `na.rm = T` caused errors regarding which function I was calling for the `fun=` argument, but spelling out `na.rm = TRUE` worked fine and all the errors about the function went away. You've spelled it out in your example here, but are there instances in your code where `TRUE` is only written as `T`?

Comment: The problem seem just to dissapear after installing rtools42-5355-5357 on R 4.2.3